# Descendant of first child

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm trying to adress the descendant/child of the first child in a list. For example:

```
<ul>
<li> 
<a>This "a" of the first list item should have a black background</a>
</li>
<li> 
<a></a>
</li>
<li> 
<a></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Using first child like "ul li:first-child" will only affect the li but not the a descendant. I'm trying to format the child(s) of the first child.

Perhaps even "ul + li a" or something, but apparently that isn't woking either.

Comment: you mean `ul > li:first-child > a`?

Answer (score 3):

```
ul li:first-child a {
    background-color:black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UbuAx/

Comment: This is working! For some reason this wasn't working earlier. Without a doubt something I did wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
ul li:first-child > * {
```

This will match all direct children of the first `<li>`.

If they're always links, you could subsitute the `*` for `a`.

Answer (score 0):

All anchors under the first list item:

```
ul li:first-child a { … }
```

Or for any descendants:

```
ul li:first-child * { … }
```

Or for only children (not grand children, etc. descendants):

```
ul li:first-child > * { … }
```

Comment: The first suggestion here is by far the best. Using a global selector (`*`) is extremely slow.

Comment: @Piers Care to back up that statement with a citation?

Comment: Google backs up @PiersMainwaring claim: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#UseEfficientCSSSelectors

Answer (score 0):

You specifically said:

```
/* a list's */
ul

/* first child's  */
> li:first-child

/* descendant or child */
*
```

or

```
ul > li:first-child *
```

Strangely, none of the other answers give you exactly what you requested, though I agree about the * global selector being non-optimal.  If you can specify, it might be nice.